List out the Skipped stages in a jenkins JOB
I am a seasoned QA Engineer tryig my hand in the world of Devops.Currently i am having some hardtime on jenkins.
I am trying to list out the skipped stages in a jenkins job.Once i succeed will run this through whole jenkins to find out what are all the jobs skipping what stages.
Here is the snippet i am running in jenkins script console.
def jobName = "cleanup-monthly"
def buildNumber = 84 // Specify the build number you're interested in

def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

if (job != null) {
    def build = job.getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)
    if (build != null && build instanceof WorkflowRun) {
        def run = build as WorkflowRun
        def execution = run.getExecution()

        println "Job Name: ${jobName}"
        println "Build Number: ${buildNumber}"
        println "Status: ${build.result}"

        println "Stages:"
        execution.getCurrentHeads().each { node ->
            if (node.getAction(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.StageAction) != null) {
                println "- ${node.getDisplayName()}"
            }
        }
    } else {
        println "Build not found for job: ${jobName} and build number: ${buildNumber}"
    }
} else {
    println "Job not found: ${jobName}"
}

I tried this going through online forums & jenkins docs. but i am unable to get the stages listed.
Can someone help me to understand what i am doing wrong.
Current output :
Job Name: cleanup-monthly
Build Number: 84
Status: SUCCESS
Stages:
Result: [FlowEndNode[id=75, exec=CpsFlowExecution[Owner[cleanup-monthly/84:cleanup-monthly #84]]]]


I'm not sure that it makes sense when there are Stage View (a must-have on Jenkins, probably available by default) and Blue Ocean UI (available by default) that provide a clear view on the actual pipeline workflow.

@AlexanderPletnev  I appreciate your confirmation! It's great to be on the same page. Managing numerous microservice teams and their jobs can be challenging. Manually checking each job's stage view to identify skipped stages can be time-consuming.
To automate this task and generate a comprehensive report, I'm exploring Groovy scripting within Jenkins. This script would ideally list all jobs and identify any stages they're skipping. This would provide valuable insights and streamline the process."
